# Bit operations in flipping coin

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was trying to understand this piece of code. I think it is using some variant of segment tree data structure but I cannot understand any bit operations in this code.

The actual question is that there are N coin and we have 1 operation and 1 query which are

1. To flip coin in range [A,B]
2. To find the number of head in range [A,B] respectively.

.

```
 #define LEAVES (131072)
 #define MSB_V (0x80000000)
 #define MSB_P (31)

 int it[2 * LEAVES];
 int A, B;    //Query range

 void flip (int i, int min, int max)
 {
    if ((min > B) || (max <= A))
    {   }
    else if ((min >= A) && ((max-1) <= B))
    {   it[i] ^= MSB_V; }
    else
    {
        int l = 2 * i;
        int r = l + 1;
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        it[l] ^= it[i] & MSB_V;
        it[r] ^= it[i] & MSB_V;
        it[i] ^= MSB_V;
        flip(l, min, mid);
        flip(r, mid, max);
        it[i] = (it[l] >> MSB_P ? mid - min - (it[l] ^ MSB_V) : it[l]) +
                (it[r] >> MSB_P ? max - mid - (it[r] ^ MSB_V) : it[r]);
    }
}

int count (int i, int min, int max)
{
    int h;
    if ((min > B) || (max <= A))
    {   h = 0; }
    else if ((min >= A) && ((max-1) <= B))
    {   h = it[i] >> MSB_P ? max - min - (it[i] ^ MSB_V) : it[i]; }
    else
    {
        int l = 2 * i;
        int r = l + 1;
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        it[l] ^= it[i] & MSB_V;
        it[r] ^= it[i] & MSB_V;
        it[i] ^= MSB_V;
        it[i] = (it[l] >> MSB_P ? mid - min - (it[l] ^ MSB_V) : it[l]) +
                (it[r] >> MSB_P ? max - mid - (it[r] ^ MSB_V) : it[r]);
        h = count(l, min, mid) + count(r, mid, max);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Can somebody please give me some hint about what is the logic behind all these bit operations

Comment: Looks like it's just XOR'ing bits to flip them. So each coin is represented by a single bit, 0/1 heads/tails.

Comment: This code has the same error in both functions: the statement `it[i] ^= MSB_V;` is followed by an assignment `it[i] = (something independent of old value it[i])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`it` represents a complete binary tree; node 1 is the root and the children of node k are 2k and 2k+1.

The leaves of the complete binary tree are the coins.  The internal nodes are the number of  coins facing a certain way (in the low 31 bits) and a "flipped" marker (in the sign bit).  If the flipped market is clear, the low 31 bits count the number of heads-up coins in the node's subtree, while, if the flipped bit is set, tails-up coins are counted.

The parameter convention used by both `find` and `count` here is that `i` is the node being counted or flipped, `min` is the lowest index represented by that node, and `max` is the highest index.  The first two tests in both `find` and `count` check whether the flip/count range (defined by `A` and `B`) is disjoint from or encompasses node `i`'s range.

What you see in `flip` is:

- If [A,B] is disjoint from [min, max], do nothing.
- If [A,B] contains [min, max], flip the flipped marker.
- Otherwise, run `flip` on the two children.  Once we've done this, the invariant here is ruined; fix it by adding up the number of heads-up coins in both children.

What you see in `count` is:

- If [A,B] is disjoint from [min, max], return 0.
- If [A,B] contains [min, max], return the count in this node.
- Otherwise, add up the counts of our children.

Comment: In flip function `it[l] ^= it[i] & MSB_V; it[r] ^= it[i] & MSB_V; it[i] ^= MSB_V;` what is the logic behind these statements? If it[i] is calculating heads-up then 31st bit of it[l] is retained otherwise flipped, same with it[r] and then it[i] is flipped, but why we need this? Cant we just do the recursive call and then appropriately calculate it[i] with the help of it[l] and it[r]

Comment: I have another doubt that if flip function doesn't recursively go down to the leaf node and stops in some intermediate node then all the node below that intermediate node will not get flipped. e.g. if N = 4, A = 1 and B = 4, and flip(1,0,N) is called so it will flip the root node and will get returned without flipping the node below it.
Can you please explain? What I am thinking wrong?

Comment: Flips are done lazily.  We keep track of whether all of a subtree's coins have been flipped.  The code snippet you mentioned "pushes" a lazy flip from a node to its children.